# Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)

Tags: css3, списки

[image: макет]

Здраствуйте,
как сделать линии соединяющие маркеры как на изображении на чистом CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}



ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
}
ul:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 4px;
    width: 1px;
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    background: #f00;      
}
ul > li{
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
ul > li:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 0;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background: #f00; 
    border-radius: 50%;    
}
ul > li:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 9px; left: 4px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #f00;     
}
ul > li:last-child:before{
    background: none;
}
ul > li:last-child:after{
    width: 40%;
    top: 39px
}
.btn{
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    position: relative; top: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: 50%;
    background: #f00;
}
.btn:before{
    top: calc(100% + 2px); 
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;    
    margin-left: -0.5px;
}
.btn:after{
    top: calc(100% + 12px);
    width: 10px;
    height: 1px;    
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)</li>
    <li>Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)</li>
    <li>Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)</li>
    <li>Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)</li>
    <li>Как сделать линии между маркерами в списках на css? (без изображений)</li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7f9vjqb/)

Comment: Для того чтоб маркеры были пустыми надо только поменять местами  before и after. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если верстка фиксированная, можно попробовать все линии сделать через background-image для главного блока.
Еще вариант, задать для списка и заголовка псевдоэлемент :after или :before выровнять его как нужно и тоже подложить фон либо задать нужную высоту и толщину в 1px.